# Yii Framework: Gii tool dropdown creation?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I'm new to Yii Framework and racking my brain over this.  I was wondering how to use the Gii tool to create a dependent dropdown/crud? I need to have a yes/no drop down field that will save the clicked state to the database, and subsequently reveal a form field to enter a number when checked "yes".  I've got this basic functionality with jquery, but will not save.  Any help is greatly appreciated, as this will help me keep my job.  Code is proprietary, so I'm hesitant to include here.  Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Post your DB-Models please! I think your ERM and Constraints are not good ... :)

Comment: Your can also try "if (!$model->save()){ var_dump($model->errors);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debug yourself. I promise, it will help ya out!

```
if (!$model->save()){ 
   var_dump($model->errors);
}
```

Comment: I've saved that code for future use, thanks.   I have another Yii question, and I'd like to know where I can learn this stuff without asking!! Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373506/yii-save-dropdown-checked-state-on-page-refresh

Comment: First: Learn PHP http://www.php.net, than learn yii -> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/ ;) ... as far as I can see, you are pretty new to PHP/OOP/MVC/. Keep it on!

Comment: Yes sir, very new, and learning as I go.  If I can complete these tasks, I keep the dev job!