# yii save dropdown checked state on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu, yii

In yii save a dropdown checked state of "yes" when the page reloads, if that is chosen?  It defaults to "No".. Thanks!!

getAttributeLabel('MULTI_PART_FORM')); ?>

```
       <td class="type-text"><?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('MULTI_PART_PO','',array( 0=>'No',1=>'Yes'), array('onChange' => "$('#MULTI_PART_VIEW').show();")); ?></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="MULTI_PART_VIEW" style="display:none">
        <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('MULTI_PART_VIEW')); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'MULTI_PART_PO',array('size'=>120,'maxlength'=>64,'value'=>$model->MULTI_PART_PO)); ?></td>
            <?php
```

Comment: 1) Did you ever made a FORM with method post working?

Comment: working on that now.  thanks!

Comment: What I exactly mean is, make a Form with HTML/PHP working and get along with $_POST/$_GET superglobals -> http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.superglobals.php in PHP. So you know how to handling this in Yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//VIEW CODE
echo CHtml::beginForm(Yii::app()->createUrl("{controllername}/save",array(/*'{controller parameter}'=>{parameter value},*/)),'post',array('id'=>'form_id'));

    echo CHtml::dropDownList('MULTI_PART_PO',$saved_dropdown_value,array( 0=>'No',1=>'Yes'), array('onChange' => "$('#MULTI_PART_VIEW').show();"));
    //dropDownList(string $name, string $select="the selected value", array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))

echo CHtml::endForm();


//CONTROLLER CODE (add function Save to accessRules array)
public function actionSave(/*{controller parameter}*/)
{
    $model=new {Modelname};

    if(isset($_POST["MULTI_PART_PO"]))
    {
        $model->multi_part_po = $_POST["MULTI_PART_PO"];
        $model->save();
    }

    $this->render('{Viewname}',array(
        'saved_dropdown_value'=>$model->multi_part_po,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that at work in an hour.  If it works, I'll get you Starbucks!

Comment: You can also call the method Save via ajax when the dropdown value has changed: $.post("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('{controllername}/Save'); ?>", {"MULTI_PART_PO": $("input[name='MULTI_PART_PO']").val()});

Comment: Thanks.  Having trouble with understanding this part: {controller parameter}'=>{parameter value}, and  $model=new {Modelname}; I believe these would bethe names of my models and controllers?  But what is the model parameter?  thanks, brand new at this!

Comment: {Modelname} ist the name of your model. {controllername} is the name of you Controller. {controller parameter} are $_GET parameters.. you dont need them for this example i just added them for the sake of completeness.